# What is the least memory-intensive way to read a Parquet file in Python? Is line-by-line possible?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

I'm writing a lambda to read records stored in Parquet files, restructure them into a `partition_key: {json_record}` format, and submit the records to a Kafka queue. I'm wondering if there's any way to do this without reading the entire table into memory at once.

I've tried using the `iter_row_groups` method from the `fastparquet` library, but my records only have one row group, so I'm still loading the entire table into memory. And I noticed that the `BufferReader` from `pyarrow` has a `readlines` method, but it isn't implemented. Is true line-by-line reading of Parquet not possible?

Might be worth pointing out that I'm working with Parquet files stored in S3, so ideally a solution would be able to read in `StreamingBody`

Comment: Currently playing around with the `ParquetFile.iter_batches` method from `pyarrow`, realizing that I was probably too fixated on reading line-by-line whereas reading in batches should still be very memory efficient

Comment: If data is in S3 and you're writing to Kafka, I would use Pyspark in EMR, not a lambda

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you may look into DuckDB and polars:

- DuckDB https://duckdb.org/2021/06/25/querying-parquet.html

One can certainly limit the query to the say top 1000 results. If you got some row index iterating through the whole parquet with duckdb and SELECT WHERE should be easy.

- polars https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_parquet.html

You may experiment with row_count_name and row_count_offset. Again, with an existing row index column reading rows as chunks is doable.